# Skat tool to determine the probability for a win

Tags: probability, skat

Does anyone know a skat tool with the following feature ?

You can enter the three hands and the contract of the solo-player (grand,spades,hearts,diamonds,clubs,null). The program determines the
winning chances assuming open cards and best play of both sides. (double-dummy-analysis)

This program would be very useful to estimate how good specific hands are to play specific contracts.

Comment: Isn't an open game with best play either a loss or a win, without any chances?

Comment: To determine the odds for a contract, only information available to the bidder should be considered: his cards, position from lead, and contract.
The main challenge for determining the odds is considering the possible distribution of the unseen cards.  For a given distribution and the assumption of perfect play, the contract is either always won or lost.